# How do I implement a Barrel Shifter?

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer, homework, alu

I'm using Multimedia logic for this particular assignment, I am to implement an ALU that performs Bitwise Rotation on the input from "A" by the amount defined by "B". Not quite sure how to approach this.

New to the topic in general, so not quite sure what other information to provide, please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: Homework, yes? Are you asking for help on the toolchain (MMLogic), or with barrel shifter design? Have you done research or tried anything so far? If not, I'm afraid you won't get much help on this homework.

Comment: There is a cheat, if your technology implements multipliers as hardware cores (like many FPGAs do). Just multiply by powers of 2. But be aware : if this is homework, it may not be what teacher is looking for...

Comment: Yes, this is homework. Yes, I'm asking for help on MML, where in I have to implement a barrel shifter. I've tried looking at implementations for barrel shifters, and I kinda know how they work, but I'm not sure how to implement since the bit can be shifted by "x" bits. So yeah, not quite sure where to start or what to look at @hacktastical

Comment: Basically, a barrel shifter is a multiplexer on each bit, where a value selects one of *n* bits reflecting the offset.

Comment: So how do I approach the question when it asks me to "Rotate A by B bits" (A and B in this particular question can be upto 4 bits)

Comment: That’s four, 4-in 1-out multiplexers wired in a way that yields the desired shift based on the B select.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to do that